# IzPack 4.3.5 branding

Tags: izpack, izpanel

I would like to remove or change the "Made with IzPack" text at the footer. I would also like to change the installer icon.

But I couldn't find any examples. I am using 4.3.5, please don't suggest using version 5.0.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you still need help...

The "Made with IzPack" is in the eng.xml file.
search for id="installer.madewith"

The Icon can be defined in your install.xml
`<resources>
  <res id="Heading.image" src="./res/img/top.png"/>
  <res id="Installer.image.0" src="./res/img/side.png"/>
  ...
</resources>`